# What's the difference between "user" and "user_reference" in PagerDuty API

Tags: pagerduty

I'm writing a terraform template to setup escalation policies.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/pagerduty/r/escalation_policy.html

I want to create an escalation policy to a specific user, but I don't know whether to specify `user` or `user_reference` as a value of `rule.target.type`. What's the difference between `user` and `user_reference` in PagerDuty API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a value of `rule.target.type`, `user` and `user_reference` are one and the same. Using either type should create an escalation policy that involves the specified user that is defined with `rule.target.id`.

Comment: Thank you! Then, I'll use `user_reference` because PagerDuty API returns the target as `user_reference` even if the target was defined as `user`.